# Counting Immutable objects in JVM

Tags: java, jvm

How can I count the total number of immutable objects of a certain type in the jvm of my application?

Comment: What is the use-case?

Comment: I want to count the growth in number of immutable objects in my jvm when I am running a JMeter load test against my REST server.

Comment: Is this **Immutable** (probably a type) or **immutable** (adjective)?

Comment: java does not have a real concept of immutable objects, not yet anyway. so how is your probably application-specfic property of them being immutable relevant to the question?

Comment: What are you trying to measure? E.g. if the code handling a request creates 2 mutable objects and 26 immutable objects (like `String`), none of them will logically exist anymore once the request completes. It may take a while before the Garbage Collector reclaims them, but that's meaningless.

Comment: I suggest you use a profiler which can tell you the number of objects in a heap.  Note, the number actually live is likely to be very different. You should only count the number after a full GC.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to figure out which are the classes that you consider to be interesting (and immutable) and use the low level instrumentation APIs that profilers and other such tools use.